# return specific values from array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that is produced from a mysql query:

```
Array ( [0] => AA [alleles] => AA [1] => 6 [total] => 6 [2] => 25.00 [percentage] => 25.00 ) 
Array ( [0] => AG [alleles] => AG [1] => 11 [total] => 11 [2] => 45.83 [percentage] => 45.83 ) 
Array ( [0] => GG [alleles] => GG [1] => 7 [total] => 7 [2] => 29.17 [percentage] => 29.17 )
```

How do I parse this data with php to show:

```
   AA 25%
   AG 45.83%
   GG 29.17%
```

Comment: I am confused what is the key/index => value here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to return two elements per array : elements 0 and 2

Depending on what language you are using ? it would be something like :

```
answer_string = Array_1[0] + " " + Array_1[2] + "%"
```

PS. in the future always tag your question with appropriate language to get more helpful answers (it wouldn't hurt to edit your question as such)

Comment: Thanks for advice on tag and language